# How to generate urls with Django based on table variable

Tags: django, django-views

I have a blog where i would like to construct my URLs in following fashion: `blah.com/blog/this-is-my-first-blog-post` where `this-is-my-first-blog-post` is the title of one specific blog post.

Is there a way to generate these types of urls based on the `title` column in my table with blogposts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be better off storing the URL key as a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield). You can determine that value by using [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify).

Then your code for the url would be something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','example_view'),
```

And you can use get_object_or_404:

```
def example_view(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Model, slug=slug)
```

Or you can use a DetailView CBV as shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

1. In django admin, you can make the field pre-populate on editing.

   ```
   prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }
   ```

   This needs to be put in the `admin.py` file.
2. In case you want to do it outside of admin, you can use a pre-save signal and use [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) as mentioned above by @schillingt above.